# R: Calculating cumulative number of unique entries

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame from several experiments. I am looking to calculate cumulative number of unique values obtained after each successive experiment.

For example, consider:

```
test <- data.frame(exp = c( rep("exp1" , 4) , rep("exp2" , 4), rep("exp3" , 4) , rep("exp4" , 5) ) , 
                   entries = c("abcd","efgh","ijkl","mnop", "qrst" , "uvwx" , "abcd","efgh","ijkl" , "qrst" , "uvwx", 
                               "yzab" , "yzab" , "cdef" , "mnop" , "uvwx" , "ghij"))

> test
    exp entries
1  exp1    abcd
2  exp1    efgh
3  exp1    ijkl
4  exp1    mnop
5  exp2    qrst
6  exp2    uvwx
7  exp2    abcd
8  exp2    efgh
9  exp3    ijkl
10 exp3    qrst
11 exp3    uvwx
12 exp3    yzab
13 exp4    yzab
14 exp4    cdef
15 exp4    mnop
16 exp4    uvwx
17 exp4    ghij
```

total number of unique entries are nine. Now I want the result to look like:

```
   exp cum_unique_entries
1  exp1    4
2  exp2    6
3  exp3    7
4  exp4    9
```

Finally I want to plot this in the form of a barplot.
I can do this with for loops approach, but feel there has to be more elegant way.

Comment: Exp1 got 4 unique entries, then adding exp2 gave total 6 unique,...

Comment: With data.table... `library(data.table); setDT(test); unique(test, by="entries")[, .N, by=exp][, cn := cumsum(N)][]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(cum_unique_entries = cumsum(!duplicated(entries))) %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  select(-entries)
```

or

```
test %>%
  mutate(cum_unique_entries = cumsum(!duplicated(entries))) %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  summarise(cum_unique_entries = last(cum_unique_entries))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     exp cum_unique_entries
  <fctr>              <int>
1   exp1                  4
2   exp2                  6
3   exp3                  7
4   exp4                  9
```

**Note:**

First find the cumulative sum of all non-duplicates (`cumsum(!duplicated(entries))`), `group_by` `exp`, and take the last `cumsum` of each group, this number would be the cumulative unique entries for each group.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite nice. For some reason I was trying cumsum( n_distinct( entries)  )

Comment: Thanks again, yours was easier for me to understand and implement to my actual problem. I was trying to summarise the results from my last two years of experiments with more than 100 experiments and around 20k observations in each. Cheers!

Comment: @ktyagi `dplyr` is quite efficient and will work well with 2M obs. However, If you have much more data than that, I recommend trying out @dww's `data.table` solution for raw speed, which is basically doing the same thing but with `data.table`.

Answer (score 4):

With `library(data.table)` we can do

```
setDT(test)[, new := cumsum(!duplicated(entries))]
test[, .(cum_unique_entries = new[.N]), by = exp]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqldf** This can be done in a single complex join:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select b.exp, count(Distinct a.entries) cum 
       from test a join test b on a.exp <= b.exp group by b.exp")
```

giving:

```
   exp cum
1 exp1   4
2 exp2   6
3 exp3   7
4 exp4   9
```

This idea could be translated into the corresponding code using the other frameworks as well although it would be rather inefficient in base and dplyr because one would have to do an n x n cartesian join and then subset it whereas SQL might optimize it to avoid producing the large intermediate result.

**2) rollapplyr** Sort `test` by `exp` and use `rollapplyr` to calculate the cumulative number of unique entries.  Then use `!duplicated(..., fromLast = TRUE)` take the last of each `exp` group

```
library(zoo)

n <- nrow(test)    
test_sorted <- test[order(test$exp), ]
len_uniq <- function(x) length(unique(x))
test_cum <- transform(test_sorted,  cum = rollapplyr(entries, 1:n, len_uniq, fill = NA))
test_cum[!duplicated(test_cum$exp, fromLast = TRUE), -2]
```

giving:

```
    exp cum
4  exp1   4
8  exp2   6
12 exp3   7
17 exp4   9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the cast function from the reshape package ([simple example](http://statmethods.net/management/reshape.html), [full reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/reshape.pdf)). 
It sould be as simple as

```
reshape::cast(test, exp~., value="entries", function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

What I'm doing is telling the function to take into account your dataset, use the `test` variable as id-variable and "ignore" all the other variables (that's the `.` meaning), adding the "metric" returned by the given function (`function(x) length(unique(x))`) computed on the column named `entries`.

It's somthing like the `SQL` aggregate functions and `group by` construct!
It's SQL equivalent is

```
SELECT exp, count(distinct entries)
FROM test
GROUP BY test
```

Comment: I get an error: Error in as.character(formula) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Sorry, I lost a `~.`... I've added it and improved the answer!