# R // datatable // cumulative count of unique names

Tags: r, datatable

I have a large table (40 Mio x 16 col) and want to calculate the cumulative number of people in a group (ID) up to the date of each row. I should be a data.table solution, my experience is that everything else is too slow given the data size.

My data:

```
names = c("Anna", "Anna", "Hans", "Karl", "Karl", "Maria", "Sara", "Sara") 
ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
timestamp = c("2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-20", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-04", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-04")

df = cbind(timestamp, ID, names) %>% 
  as.data.table
```

Outcome I am looking for:

```
cum_count = c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2,2)
```

My attempt, which is not functional:

```
df[, `:=` (cum_count = cumsum(names) - 1), by = ID]
```

Comment: Since the issue is speed at size, I would suggest using `set.seed` for reproducibility and sharing code to generate an example with at least 1M rows and similar group sizes to what you have in your real data. Different solutions will scale up differently, and some may be better for many small groups while others better for larger groups.

Comment: On the other hand, if you just want a working solution, I would suggest [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47836031/903061). `df[, cum_count := cumsum(!duplicated(names)), by = ID]` should be reasonably quick. Make sure you `setkey` on your table first for maximum speed, and to make sure it's in the date order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option in `data.table`:

```
DT[, cum_count := {
        ri <- rleid(x)

        glast <- which(ID!=shift(ID)) - 1L
        d <- replace(rep(NA_integer_, .N), glast + 1L, ri[glast])
        d <- nafill(replace(d, 1L:glast[1L], 0L), "locf")

        ri - d
    }]
```

data (I have changed `names` column to x to avoid confusion with the function `names`):

```
x = c("Anna", "Anna", "Hans", "Karl", "Karl", "Maria", "Sara", "Sara") 
ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
timestamp = c("2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-20", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-04", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-04")
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(timestamp, ID, x)
```

Would be interested to know the timing on actual dataset.